# c# load csv file and sort columns

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` set up with elements and some identifying characteristics as column headers.

```
Col 1    Col 2     Col 3         4  5   6  7 ...
Sample , Symbol, Symbol Color, Na, K, Mg, Mn...
```

I can load `CSV` or `text tab delimited` files currently but the formatting has to match the datagridview.  Is there a way to load a `CSV` of element data with `column headers` in random order, and then place them in the columns you desire.

Currently, the csv must be formatted in the same order as the `datagridview`:

```
Na, K, Mg, Mn.... 
88, 5, 6, 16...
56, 7, 33, 12...
```

Is it possible, if the data was in a different order to have it sorted to the format of the existing `datagridview`:

```
Mg, Mn, Na, K.... 
6, 16, 88, 5...
33, 12, 56, 7...
```

There may be missing columns from the imported file sometimes and thats ok. I have figured out how to hide the columns of empty data.

Comment: Do you use any library for this? Or just .NET File IO to read the `csv` file?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use some File Library like [FileHelper](http://filehelpers.net) to perform the actions. Its free and opensource with some great stuff like reading `csv` or any formatted data file, read data asynchronously, define `column` order for entity.

**Edit:**

1. **Handling missing value:** Create custom handler to handle the missing value or can be defined the data as `nullable` For more info http://www.filehelpers.net/example/MissingValues/MissingValuesNullable/
2. **Custom order:** Use `ColumnOrder` attribute to define the column order

Comment: How does it address changing column order or missing columns issue?

Answer (score -1):

This is a very simple way to do it.

First create a class like this;

```
    private class MyColumns
    {
        public string Na { get; set; }
        public string K { get; set; }
        public string Mg { get; set; }
        public string Mn { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you can parse your csv like this.

```
        var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\kosalaw\myfile.csv"); //read all lines from the csv file
        MyColumns[] AllColumns = new MyColumns[allLines.Count() -1]; //create an array of MyColumns class
        var colHeaders = allLines[0].Split(new[]{"\",\""},StringSplitOptions.None).ToList(); // Identify columns headers
        for (int index = 1; index < allLines.Length; index++)//loop through the lines. We skip first line as it is the column header
        {
            var line = allLines[index];
            var lineColumns = line.Split(new[] { "\",\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None); //split each line in to columns
            AllColumns[index - 1] = new MyColumns //now use column header to identify the exact column.
            {
                K = lineColumns[colHeaders.IndexOf("K")],
                Mg = lineColumns[colHeaders.IndexOf("Mg")],
                Mn = lineColumns[colHeaders.IndexOf("Mn")],
                Na = lineColumns[colHeaders.IndexOf("Na")]
            };
        }
```

Comment: .Split() is rarely a good way to parse csv data. It's slow, and it will almost always bump into an edge case and fail against real-world data.

Comment: Any examples of such cases?

Comment: The main one is fields that include commas or newlines as part of the data, whether or not they're quoted or escaped, but there are other ways to break it,too.

Comment: If it's csv and if the csv data has a risk of having commas in the fields, the fields have to be double quoted. Based on that I changed my code. If the fields have line breaks, OP can use `File.ReadAllText` and then split. The answer is obviously based on certain assumptions. If you have a better solution, feel free to add it, so the OP and everyone else can benefit from it.

Comment: .Split() still won't work when there are commas in the fields, even with double quotes. The better answer is to use a dedicated csv parser. There are many easy, fast, lightweight, and free options available, and there are at least three already built into the .Net framework.